# New install of Ubuntu 20.04, Mouse through KM switch not fully working

Tags: drivers, 20.04, mouse, kvm-switch

I am a moderate Steam gamer and I finally made the disciplined choice to switch to Ubuntu, for the third time in my life. I am very paranoid about security and I am dreaming of buying a Libreboot laptop when they are available. This is a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 LTS install with no extensions or modifications, just app installs from the terminal and sometimes from the Ubuntu application store.

**The PC I am running this on is:** 
Asus x79 Sabertooth mobo.
Intel i7 3930k 6-core CPU at 3.3 GHZ.
G-Skill 8x4 GB Quad-Channel RAM at 1600 MHZ.
Samsung 1TB NVME M.2 SSD through PCI-e Adapter.
AMD RX 580 8GB GPU.
Seagate Firecuda 2TB SATA drive.

**Since the install** dialogs and ever since, Ubuntu 20.04 has recognized my Patriot macro mouse as a keyboard. The macro keys work but the laser movement does not move my cursor. I do not suspect that Patriot has a Linux driver, but the mouse is crucial and I need to get it fully recognized. I believe that the mouse was recognized in Ubuntu 18.04 but perhaps with the newer Linux kernel is was removed. Running lsusb, I do not even see any entry that correlates to this device, or even the companion Patriot macro'd keyboard which seems to work just fine. The 'SINOWEALTH' mouse is the 2nd mouse I am using to control my cursor. Please assist.

Patriot-brand Macro Mouse

[image]

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 1058:25fb Western Digital Technologies, Inc. easystore 25FB
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 258a:1007 SINOWEALTH Wired Gaming Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 007: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 032: ID 0e6f:0162 Logic3
Bus 003 Device 031: ID 0d8c:0005 C-Media Electronics, Inc. Blue Snowball
Bus 003 Device 030: ID 0c45:7e0c Microdia
Bus 003 Device 029: ID 04d9:a12e Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 028: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**UPDATE**
The mouse is a Patriot Viper v570 mouse, and the critical piece of info that I had forgotten about was that this mouse is connected to my Ubuntu 20.04 PC through a KM switch, which I cannot replace/remove.
What I discovered today was that plugging the mouse directly into my PC makes it work, and plugging it then back into the KM switch and through that to the PC ALSO makes it work, but then restarting my PC it will then NOT work again.

**So I suspect that the solution is to plug the mouse into the PC, then to the KM switch, and make this recognition permanent at boot! Please help I with this!**

Comment: Hi, out of all these, I can help you with only one thing (sorry it's not gonna answer anything yet): I believe people here will advise you to put each of your questions in separate posts. It's not gonna be super-straightforward, because I guess the site will force a few hours of waiting time between each question, but here it's really important that people deal with one issue in one thread...

Comment: Then with each question, go into details as deep as you can: which part of the screen are those application icons that don't work, which exact Thunderbird settings files did you copy from where and where exactly pasted them and so on. Always indicate the Ubuntu version, and anything installed that deviates from the standard Ubuntu flavor (themes extensions etc.). Perhaps it's gonna be tiring and frustrating a bit in the beginning; therefore go for the most important questions first, so that your stamina will last until you reach a solution with them. I wish you luck and success.

Comment: Thank you. I hope I can keep this current question up even though it's four questions. I edited my answer with your suggestions. I did not have nearly this much trouble the last time I tried to install Ubuntu, which was with 18.04. You're right about the stamina.

Comment: Hi, I was looking at this mouse compatibility and found your post. I´m glad the mouse works ok directly to the PC. To help you, knowing what's between the mouse and the PC is critical to understand why it's behaving this way. You should probably specify what is a "KM switch", are you referring to a KVM, as in keyboard, video & mouse switch device? You should probably share the details of that device, as in: brand, model and how it's plugged (usb?).

Answer (score 0):

I see you found the solution here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/686826

> The Rosewill USB-3 KM switch must, on certain hardware configurations,
> be hooked up to a USB-2 port in order to make full functionality!

And there was an issue with the USB Hub and USB port combination you were using.

Apparently according to your messages there, it seems the mouse works, with macros included, while plugged directly without a hub:

> In the instance where everything is connected without the switch,
> everything works fine. The mouse runs as a mouse and the extra macro
> keys work, too.

ps. I'm posting this answer for future reference in case someone else gets to this post looking for information on the Viper V570 compatibility with Linux.